# Removing Admin Bar Node Based on Role

Tags: user-roles, admin-menu, dashboard

I have a custom role, `grocery`, that I would like to remove the "new content" (the + New dropdown) node from the top admin bar while this role is logged in. I have the following function but it is removing it currently for all roles including admin. Would like to find a way to limit this to just 'grocery' custom role.

functions.php

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_new_content_menu', 999 );

function remove_new_content_menu( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-content' );
}
```

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

[`WP_User`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) has a [roles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User#Public_Properties) `array`.

Get the current user with [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) and check if your role is in the array.

---

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_new_content_menu', PHP_INT_MAX );

function remove_new_content_menu( $wp_admin_bar ) {

    // get the current user
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    // define roles that cannot see the `new content` button
    $blacklisted_roles = array('grocery', 'subscriber');

    // remove the button if the current user has a blacklisted role
    if( array_intersect($blacklisted_roles, $user->roles ) ) {
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-content' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the role of the current user

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_new_content_menu', 999 );

function remove_new_content_menu( $wp_admin_bar ) {
   $user = wp_get_current_user();
   if ( $user && in_array( 'grocery', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-content' );
    }
}
```

Although a better option may be to check for a particular capability as role names may change.